# Can anybody confirm a successful flash of open gapps on genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, genymotion

While not succeeding in flashing gapps on genymotion emulator I would like to check if there is any known case that someone actually managed to install gapps on genymotion emulator.

Configuration:
Windows 10, 64 AMD proc
Genymotion 2.8.1
Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.14

Devices I tried varied: 5.1. 6.0, 7.0 custom phones, Nexus 6P all included in genymotion.

I used gapps found at http://opengapps.org/.
I used the following archives: x86 platform,
 android 5.1, 6.0, 7.0, 
 variants pico, nano, micro, mini, full, stock
 archives from 2nd february, 4th february, and some from 5th february

I have tried all possible combinations from above. Not even a single one works.

So, I need confirmation that it is even possible to flash this gapps archives.

Anyone?

Comment: Would downvoter care to explain? Perhaps downvoter cannot read English. In that case I recommend translate.google.com

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Perhaps. But on the other side most of the emulator users are developers with similar needs as mine. Though I could post the question there also.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm success using both 6.0.0 and 7.0.0 Custom Tablet devices AND the equivalent nano version of opengapps.

Here is my setup:

- Genymotion 2.8.0
- Open Gapps 20170613 x86 (not x86_64) NANO variant
- Custom Tablet devices (6.0.0 or 7.0.0) with varying resolutions
- MacOS Sierra
- VirtualBox 5.1.16

I "flashed" it the normal way by dragging and dropping the opengapps zip file onto the running Genymotion window.

Of note is that 6.0.0 does seem to be more reliable/repeatable in my testing. I can't comment on whether or not it works with Phone devices as I've not tried it.